# Download image from SQL Server

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm using vb.net window based and I want to get or download the FileImage in my SQL server. In ASP.NET I can download it via this code. But I want to translate it to windows based. Can you help me please?

Thanks,

```
        Dim oFileType As String = oPortal.GetDs("FileType")
    Dim oFile As Byte() = oPortal.GetDs("FileImage")
    Dim oRecordKey As String = oPortal.GetDs("FileName")

    Response.ContentType = "image/" & oFileType
    If Request.QueryString("open") <> "" Then 
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & oRecordKey) 
    End If

    Response.BinaryWrite(oFile)
    Response.End()
```

Comment: Got it. File.WriteAllBytes(oPath & oFileName, WebCtrl.GetDs("FileImage"))

Comment: Can you please add it as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. File.WriteAllBytes(oPath & oFileName, WebCtrl.GetDs("FileImage"))